# Running a batch file in powershell

Tags: powershell, backup

I am using the application LabTech to write scripts for Leo backup. I have a batch file on my local C drive (backup.bat). I need that file to run when a backup fails. How would I do this in powershell with commands? I looked on Google and could not find anything concrete.

Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: how does your powershell script know when a backup fails ?

Comment: It checks the log file and makes sure that the date is current, if it doesn't then it sends out an email. I want it to run that batch file instead.

Comment: Not seeing your script, i believe you can just delete the email line, and run the bat.file directly in powershell.  Try dot source `.\backup.bat` or full path.   Otherwise, we can get fancy and use cmdlet 'Start-Process' if needed.

Comment: Yeah, LabTech is weird... It is PowerShell for people who do not know powershell haha. I can add lines of Powershell script and I just need the line that will run a batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, used the -wait switch so that your powershell script pauses until the backup.bat is complete and the hidden switch so that it runs invisibly.

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Backup.bat' -Wait -WindowStyle Hidden
```

Comment: or there is the -nonewwindow switch as well.  http://ss64.com/ps/start-process.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing email line (or add under it)

```
& "path\to\your\file.bat"
```

if there are spaces. If not:

```
path\to\your\file.bat
```